# Application installer add extention to my browser. Is mavericks following the path of Windows?

Tags: macos, install, firefox, torrent

I have use `OS X 10.6.8` for years and just recently did a fresh installation of Mavericks. One of the nicest aspects of OS X was the fact that after three years of use and installing tons of application, none of them, ever added any toolbar or extension to my firefox. As appose to windows that after couple of weeks, the browser looks like a circus.

Today during installing `uTorrent` on Mavericks, I noticed that my firefox was reset and upon opening my home page changed to yahoo as well as my default search engine. Later I noticed that it has also added an extension to my browser.

Is this a flaw in the Apple new OS? Was it always there and I was just lucky in three years of using Snow Leopard? Is there some kind of security mechanism that I have to enable?

Comment: One Firefox torrent plugin has nothing to do with Mavericks. &mu;Torrent added that behavior at any point between the times you installed the plugin.

Comment: @Rob, The picture was just there for the humor. I will remove it if it is distracting. The point is, in snow leopard there was no way that installer could do such a thing.

Comment: Installing browser plugins during SW installation was also possible with OS X versions before Mavericks. In fact this has nothing to do with the OS at all but solely with the applications you are installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During installation many installers, not just uTorrent. (Also Daemon Tools for example on Windows) try to install a lot of **stuff** on your computer.

If you accept one of the ***offers*** (which looks like an agreement), you end up with stupid plugins in your browser and other default search tools - this is exactly what you're facing right now.

I would strongly recommend you to open the installer again and notice the **3rd party installers** which are hidden inside the uTorrent installation program so you can spot them in future installations.

For now, to fix this problem:
 ***Remove the toolbars / plugins manually and set back Google (or whatever your default search provider was) as default search engine.***

To make this answer complete, the same could happen to you on Snow Leopard. This is just the way the installer **(ab)uses** the way you grant access in installing an application as Administrator.

Comment: You know, it didn't ask for admin password.

Comment: Many users click these warnings away without even reading them. Do you have a password set?

Comment: I do have password set. I admit that I was fooled! There was written an offer and I automatically considered it as an agreement.

Comment: That's their ***power*** they take advantage from, as I tried to explain in the answer.

Comment: Before I accept, I have few of questions if you kindly help me with. First, why firefox didn't prompt me? Why I wasn't asked for my password by mavericks. Finally, I trashed the app but I'm afraid some processes or services or some sneakiness have remained. How can I be sure of that?

Comment: @Pouya that's something I cannot tell you. I know that FireFox has an option to warn you about installation of Plugins. - I personally think it's weird that uTorrent is not anymore a drag and drop installation any more as it was before. You get prompted for password when drag the file to the /Applications folder at that point. -- How can you be sure about that? Set back a time capsule backup if you have any. You might want to add a new question about that.